# Create replica of Azure DB for my SQL Server using powershell

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

While creating replica of Azure DB for my SQL Server using powershell getting the below error. Please help me to fix.

**Command to create replica of DB server:**

**1st command tried:**

$TargetDBServerName2= Get-AzMySqlServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetDBServerName
New-AzMySqlReplica -Master $TargetDBServerName2 -Replica $TargetDBServerName-replica -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

**2nd command tried:**

Get-AzMySqlServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetDBServerName | New-AzMySqlReplica -Replica $TargetDBServerName-replica -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

**Error when I ran first command:**

PS /home/praveen> `New-AzMySqlReplica -Master $TargetDBServerName2 -Replica $TargetDBServerName-replica -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName`
New-AzMySqlServer_Create: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/Az.MySql/1.0.0/custom/New-AzMySqlReplica.ps1:139
Line |
139 |            Az.MySql.internal\New-AzMySqlServer @PSBoundParameters
|            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: '0268ff12-7c60-49de-8de5-ccdb844d8329'

**Error when I ran 2nd command:**

PS /home/praveen> `Get-AzMySqlServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $TargetDBServerName | New-AzMySqlReplica -Replica $TargetDBServerName-replica -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName`
New-AzMySqlServer_Create: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules/Az.MySql/1.0.0/custom/New-AzMySqlReplica.ps1:139
Line |
139 |            Az.MySql.internal\New-AzMySqlServer @PSBoundParameters
|            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: '3aea208b-0a59-4be9-ad95-aef3593b2c71'

Comment: you are creating read replica database or normal replica database?

Comment: @PratikLad-MT Its read replica only. Kindly help me to fix that issue.